# Android: Reset last choice made in alertDialog.Builder with setSingleChoiceItems

Tags: android

I have an `AlertDialog.Builder` with a `setSingleChoiceItems`. The problem is that every time it appears it doesn't clean the last choice made. I should have some 'cleanState' on my onClick method, but I can't do it.
Can you please help me?

The code that I have:

```
public void test(){
     final CharSequence myList[] = { "Option 1", "Option 2" };
     AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     private int selected1 = 0;

    builder.setTitle("Please choose one option:");
    //builder.setCancelable(true);

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(myList, selected1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            selected1 = which;
        }

    });

    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the checkboxes in your `AlertDialog`, try something like this:

```
alertDialog.getListView().setItemChecked(which, false);
```

For each item in `alertDialog`.

Comment: @porthfind You might want to consider writing your own dialog class. It wouldn't be much work.